# Leaderboard not showing up - Android Native Plugin

Tags: android, plugins, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I was using an Android Native Plugin to connect to the leaderboard. At first, I made the application to connect to the google service using

`GooglePlayConnection.instance.connect();`

then when a button is clicked, the function below will be called.

```
public void ShowLeaderboard(string leaderboardName)
{
    GooglePlayManager.instance.ShowLeaderBoard("leaderboard_score");

}
```

The application shows the connecting to box, but when i clicked on the button to show the leaderboard, nothing happens.

Then I tried to combine the two function into one like below, but the leaderboard is not showing either. The first click will show connecting to google play service box, but the second time did not show the leaderboard.

```
public void LeaderboardButton(){
    if(GooglePlayConnection.state == GPConnectionState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        GooglePlayManager.instance.ShowLeaderBoard("leaderboard_score");
        } else{
        GooglePlayConnection.instance.connect ();
    }
}
```

I would like to know is it because of the code or because of the settings in the android native window-> edit settings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have everything in your Google Play Developer Console setup right, with that being said after reading the documentation I believe line 3 should be `GooglePlayManager.instance.ShowLeaderBoardsUI("leaderboard_score");`

Comment: but there is a function called `public void ShowLeaderBoard(string leaderboardName)` with `AN_GMSGeneralProxy.showLeaderBoard (leaderboardName)` in GooglePlayManager. What is the difference between ShowLeaderBoardsUI and ShowLeaderBoard?

Comment: I don't know, but reading the documentation of Android Native Plugin from the Asset Store it says "To display a leaderboard, call ShowLeaderBoardsUI: `GooglePlayManager.Instance.ShowLeaderBoardsUI ();` or you can show specific leaderboard UI with the ShowLeaderBoardById method: `GooglePlayManager.Instance.ShowLeaderBoardById (LEADERBOARD_ID);` I've looked for the difference but I can't find it off of just reading the documentation.